# Creating a function to separate first and second integer in c

Tags: c, function

I would like to make a function to find the separate the first and second digit of a number

```
int first_digit(int number) {
  if(number / 10) {
  }
return number/10;
}
```

Is this correct? Do I need the if statement or can I just return number/10 ? (as seen below)

```
int second_number(int number) {
return number % 10;
}
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: first digit of `number` is `number % 10`, second number is `(number div 10) % 10`

Comment: So what do you want your functions to do if the input is, say, `7`?

Comment: correct words is beginning of correct programming. Digits, define order You count etc

Comment: What’s required if the input is 123456789?  I’d normally regard 1as the first digit.  Your code won’t find that.

Answer (score 3):

getting first digit is easy:

```
int first_digit(int number){
    return number % 10;
}
```

the second digit is

```
int second_number(int number) {
    return (number / 10) % 10;
}
```

there is only one problem with second digit: for numbers like 1,2,3 second_number will return 0 and so it will for numbers like 103, in short when second_number returns 0 the caller won't know whether the number has only one digit or that second digit is really 0.

If you want the caller to know you can return -1 when passed number only has one digit like so:

```
int second_number(int number) {
    int nDiv = number / 10;
    if(nDiv==0)
        return -1;
    return nDiv % 10;
}
```

Comment: Usually we call `number % 10` the "last digit".

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need if statement here,you can run

```
int first_digit(int number){
 if(number / 10) {`}`
return number/10;
}
```

this code without using if statement.
there is no effect,on the output so it doesn't matter you put if condition here or not.
i answered as per your question maybe it helpful to you.